# Streamed tables don't display table size in UI

Tags: google-bigquery

Some of the recent tables created by streaming don't display table size:
[image]

The same table next day shows its size:
[image]

Why is there such a delay in the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streamed data is written to a buffer that gets flushed periodically (the rate depends on how quickly data is being ingested). We don't update the table metadata (including size) until the data is flushed. Does this cause problems? If so, if you file a feature request at the BigQuery public issue tracker we'll look into doing more immediate size calculation.

Comment: For us none of the tables in the live dataset are having these counts. `aerobic-forge-504`